# Extract last two words from my string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I trying extract last words from my string.

Example

**Input String :** `GGG_FFFF_AAAA_BBBBBB_CCC_DDDDD`

**Result**

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╗
║ FIRST_COL ║ SECOND_COL ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╣
║ CCC       ║ DDDDD      ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I have the below code working.

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(50) = 'GGG_FFFF_AAAA_BBBBBB_CCC_DDDDD'

SELECT 
Reverse(LEFT(Stuff(Reverse(@STR), 1, Charindex('_', Reverse(@STR)) + 1 - 1, ''), Charindex('_', Stuff(Reverse(@STR), 1, Charindex('_', Reverse(@STR)) + 1 - 1, '')) - 1)) as FIRST_COL,
Reverse(LEFT(Reverse(@STR), Charindex('_', Reverse(@STR)) - 1)) as SECOND_COL
```

Is there any simpler to achieve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use XML:

```
DECLARE @input nvarchar(max) = 'GGG_FFFF_AAAA_BBBBBB_CCC_DDDDD',
        @x xml

SELECT @x = CAST('<a>'+REPLACE(REVERSE(@input),'_','</a><a>')+'</a>' as xml)


SELECT  REVERSE(@x.value('/a[2]','nvarchar(max)')) as FIRST_COL,
        REVERSE(@x.value('/a[1]','nvarchar(max)')) as SECOND_COL
```

Output:

```
FIRST_COL   SECOND_COL
CCC         DDDDD
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PARSENAME` (starting with 2012)

```
DECLARE @Val NVARCHAR(100)= 'AAAA_BBB_CCC_DDDDD'
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Val, '_', '.'), 1) -- DDDDD
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Val, '_', '.'), 2) -- CCC
```

Note: This is not correct for more than 3 `_`

Comment: Length is not fixed it can have more than 4 `_`

Comment: Your answer is better one from others

Comment: @SandipPatel - Problem is it will not work when you have more than 3 `_`

Comment: @Prdp I thought You always have 3 `_`

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @Var1  VARCHAR(MAX)='AAAA_BBB_CCC_DDDDDDD'

----SELECT CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@Var1))
SELECT RIGHT(@Var1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@Var1))-1)


-----SELECT REPLACE(@Var1,RIGHT(@Var1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@Var1))),'')

--SELECT CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(
--  REPLACE(@Var1,RIGHT(@Var1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@Var1))),'')
--))

SELECT RIGHT(
REPLACE(@Var1,RIGHT(@Var1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@Var1))),''),
CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(
    REPLACE(@Var1,RIGHT(@Var1,CHARINDEX('_',REVERSE(@Var1))),'')
))-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a user defined custom function as follows

```
DECLARE @Val NVARCHAR(100)= 'AAAA_BBB_CCC_DDDDD'
;with cte as (
    select id, val, MAX(id) over (partition by 1) maximum 
    from dbo.SQLSplitString(@Val,'_',1,0) t
)
select val from cte where id >= maximum - 1
```

You can find the [SQL split function codes](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) here

Answer (score 1):

Try this : While storing string, store it as revers that reduces the UN-neccessary calls to make string reverse

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(50) =REVERSE('GGG_FFFF_AAAA_BBBBBB_CCC_DDDDD')

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@STR,0, CHARINDEX('_',@STR))),
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@STR,CHARINDEX('_',@STR,CHARINDEX('_',@STR))+1,3))
```

Comment: You need to reverse the result then